# Css tooltip direction from right to left

Tags: html, css

I am using the below code to show tooltip. It's working fine. But it's direction from left to right.I need the tooltip from right to left. Please help me to change this direction issue.

```
a.tooltip {outline:none; } a.tooltip strong {line-height:30px;} a.tooltip:hover {text-decoration:none;} a.tooltip span { z-index:10;display:none; padding:14px 20px; margin-top:-30px; margin-left:28px; width:340px; line-height:16px; } a.tooltip:hover span{ display:inline; position:absolute; color:#111; border:1px solid #DCA; background:#fffAF0;} .callout {z-index:20;position:absolute;top:30px;border:0;left:-12px;}

<a href="#" class="tooltip"> Tooltip 
<span> <img class="callout" src="callout.gif" />Testing</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried like this:

```
a.tooltip span {
    direction:rtl;
}
```